# OSB JCA transport does not support adapter type: CUSTOM_ADAPTER

Tags: jdeveloper, weblogic11g, osb

I am into testing OSB adapter for our buisness solution. Here I was able to create SOA composite editor project in Jdeveloper and from that I got WSDL and JCA binding files for outbound type.

Using those files, I need to create project OSB server and have to activate it. PFB screen shot.
[image]

While activating it by submitting the session, I hit with error meesage "OSB JCA transport does not support adapter type: CUSTOM_ADAPTER" like the below screen shot.

[image]

Error Logs:

> com.bea.wli.sb.transports.TransportException: Failed to create JCABindingService for wsdl: servicebus:/WSDL/OBTest/OFSOutBound, exception: com.bea.wli.sb.transports.TransportException: OSB JCA transport does not support adapter type: CUSTOM_ADAPTER
>   com.bea.wli.sb.transports.TransportException: OSB JCA transport does not support adapter type: CUSTOM_ADAPTER
>    at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.jca.binding.JCATransportOperationBindingServiceImpl.init(JCATransportOperationBindingServiceImpl.java:56)
>    at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.jca.binding.JCATransportOutboundOperationBindingServiceImpl.init(JCATransportOutboundOperationBindingServiceImpl.java:38)
>    at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.jca.JCATransportEndpoint.initJCABindingService(JCATransportEndpoint.java:97)
>    at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.jca.JCATransportProvider.createEndPoint(JCATransportProvider.java:300)
>    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>    at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.Util$1.invoke(Util.java:83)
>    at $Proxy133.createEndPoint(Unknown Source)
>    at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.ResourceLifecycleListenerImpl$EndPointOperationCreate.execute(ResourceLifecycleListenerImpl.java:907)
>    at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.ResourceLifecycleListenerImpl.processServiceNotifications(ResourceLifecycleListenerImpl.java:342)
>    at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.ResourceLifecycleListenerImpl.endChangeNotification(ResourceLifecycleListenerImpl.java:125)
>    at com.bea.wli.sb.transports.TransportManagerImpl.endChangeNotification(TransportManagerImpl.java:1224)
>    at com.bea.wli.sb.service.ServiceChangeListener.endChangeNotification(ServiceChangeListener.java:142)
>    at com.bea.wli.config.impl.ResourceListenerNotifier.sendChangeNotificationsInContext(ResourceListenerNotifier.java:423)
>    at com.bea.wli.config.impl.ResourceListenerNotifier.sendChangeNotifications(ResourceListenerNotifier.java:338)
>    at com.bea.wli.config.impl.ResourceListenerNotifier.sendChangeNotifications(ResourceListenerNotifier.java:321)
>    at com.bea.wli.config.impl.ResourceListenerNotifier.beforePrepare(ResourceListenerNotifier.java:97)
>    at com.bea.wli.config.transaction.TransactionListenerWrapper.beforePrepare(TransactionListenerWrapper.java:64)
>    at com.bea.wli.config.transaction.TransactionManager.notifyBeforePrepare(TransactionManager.java:1094)
>    at com.bea.wli.config.transaction.TransactionManager._prepareForCommit(TransactionManager.java:654)
>    at com.bea.wli.config.transaction.TransactionManager.prepareForCommit(TransactionManager.java:609)
>    at com.bea.wli.config.deployment.server.ServerDeploymentReceiver._prepare(ServerDeploymentReceiver.java:417)
>    at com.bea.wli.config.deployment.server.ServerDeploymentReceiver.access$700(ServerDeploymentReceiver.java:70)
>    at com.bea.wli.config.deployment.server.ServerDeploymentReceiver$1.run(ServerDeploymentReceiver.java:246)
>    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
>    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
>    at com.bea.wli.config.deployment.server.ServerDeploymentReceiver.prepare(ServerDeploymentReceiver.java:213)
>    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
>    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
>    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)
>    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
>    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
>    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)

Help from someone is much appreciated.

Please do reply if you need further details.

Thanks,
Madhan

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the above problem by declaring CUSTOM_ADAPTER in OSBSupportedAdapters.xml file.

And placed this xml file under D:\OSB\OSB_Test\Oracle_OSB1\config\adapter.

```
<jca:osb-supported-adapters xmlns:jca="http://www.bea.com/wli/sb/transports/jca">
      <jca:adapter-type>CUSTOM_ADAPTER</jca:adapter-type>
</jca:osb-supported-adapters>
```

The above xml file solve my issue, while activating project in OSB server.

Thanks,
Madhan